# Is this C function correct?

Tags: python, c, url-rewriting

First, sorry about my English.
Second, I'm rewriting a code from Python to C and this function is confusing me.
First, the function is called:

```
idx = fc.get_most_external_binary_connective_index(formula)
```

This is the function:

```
def get_most_external_binary_connective_index(formula):
 parentheses_counter, idx = 0, 0
 for i in formula:
  if i == '(':
   parentheses_counter += 1
  elif i == ')':
   parentheses_counter -= 1
  elif parentheses_counter == 1 and (i == '&' or i == '#' or i == '>'):
   return idx
  idx += 1
 return None
```

This is my function written in C (it is in Portuguese):

```
int existe_um_conectivo_aqui(char *formula)
{
    int tamanhoFormula = strlen(formula);

    int contador_parenteses = 0;
    int idx = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoFormula; i++)
    {
        if (formula[i] == '(')
        {
            contador_parenteses = contador_parenteses + 1;
        }
        else if (formula[i] == ')')
        {
            contador_parenteses = contador_parenteses - 1;
        }
        else if ((contador_parenteses == 1) && (formula[i] == '&' || formula[i] == '#' || formula[i] == '>'))
        {
            return idx;
        }
        idx = idx + 1;
        return NULL;
    }
```

Is it correct? I didn't understand the final of the Python code when return idx and after the
'else if' the idx receive a +1 and return none.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or a work-checking site. You can ask about specific problems, but not just “Is it correct?” You should test your code by exercising it in a program with a variety of test cases. I will note that `return NULL;` is incorrect. C does not provide a way to indicate a “null” value for integers. `NULL` is for pointers. You will have to modify the specification of the function to indicate a “null” result by choosing some integer value to mean a null result, such as −1.

Comment: Please indent your code. This is a requirement in Python, and makes it easier to read in C.

Comment: `return NULL` (or whatever you replace it with, as @EricPostpischil pointed out) should not be in the loop. This will end the loop after the first character.

Comment: And no it isn't correct. Even if you fix the return value of `return NULL;` to something meaningful of a function expecting an `int` result, look *where* it is: the inner tail of the outer loop. That means at the tail of the first iteration you increment `idx`, then just return, foregoing the rest of the loop iterations. Of course **testing** your code would show this, so.. You also didn't include the rest of the function (missing closing `}`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're making a mistake here your python code as wrong indentation

```py
def get_most_external_binary_connective_index(formula):
 parentheses_counter, idx = 0, 0
 for i in formula:
   if i == '(':
     parentheses_counter += 1
   elif i == ')':
     parentheses_counter -= 1
   elif parentheses_counter == 1 and (i == '&' or i == '#' or i == '>'):
     return idx
   idx += 1
 return None
```

Which 'translate' (by using your code) to:

```c
int existe_um_conectivo_aqui(char *formula)
{
    int tamanhoFormula = strlen(formula);

    int contador_parenteses = 0;
    int idx = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoFormula; i++)
    {
        if (formula[i] == '(')
        {
            contador_parenteses = contador_parenteses + 1;
        }
        else if (formula[i] == ')')
        {
            contador_parenteses = contador_parenteses - 1;
        }
        else if ((contador_parenteses == 1) && (formula[i] == '&' || formula[i] == '#' || formula[i] == '>'))
        {
            return idx;
        }
        idx = idx + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The last return should be outside the loop otherwise it will break the loop by exiting the function. Also changed `NULL` to `-1` since it's an int function.

You should experiment by yourself and not just randomly post code as if we were there to check it.